# how to add tablet resolution support in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Using ConstraintLayout I saw this problem: on phones, the resolution of my widgets is normal and takes up almost all of the 
screen space:

[image]

But when I switch to the resolution of the tablets, all the widgets become small and cannot be viewed on the screen:

[image]

How to make the resolution of widgets look normal on all resolutions and devices?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_l"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="329dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="57dp"
        android:layout_y="202dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="120dp"
        android:layout_y="112dp"
        android:text="start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.647" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/X_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_x="118dp"
        android:layout_y="608dp"
        android:text="x:"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/O_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/O_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/O_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/O_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_x="116dp"
        android:layout_y="661dp"
        android:text="o:"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.153"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.139"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/O_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/table_l"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.151"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/X_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create layout xml files for different screen size. For example; If your app running in Tablet(7 inch), you must create new layout as a layout-sw600dp.

Look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I created a layout, but what should I write there?
On <item name = "main" type = "layout"> @ layout / main_twopanes </item> he swears.

Comment: You should redesign every page. So, All element copy in main layout and then paste other page layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using fixed sizes and x/y positions for layouts. There might be exceptions, but in general, all views should be able to dynamically resize themselves. That means, you almost never use fixed values for widths but instead `wrap_content` or `match_parent`. After 4 years of android development I also have to find one case where I ever needed the `layout_x` and `layout_y` XML tags.

Otherwise, this layout will be small on big screens and it won't fit on small screens.

For 90% of layouts, all you need is `ConstraintLayout` and maybe `LinearLayout`. `RelativeLayout`s have become mostly obsolete.

Explaining how to properly arrange your ui would be to exhaustive here. Instead, I recommend you to take the time to go through a tutorial like this [google codelab on building a responsive UI with constraintlayouts](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0). If done correctly, you can build one UI which looks good an smartphones and tablets.

But if you want to have an entirely different layout for tablets, then @Mustafa Yanık's approach is correct. Then you need to create a second layout in a different subfolder.